# Need help - error: ';' expected is displayed even though I have included semi colon in the code

Tags: java

Some one please let me know whiy I am getting an error while trying yo execute following code. Why ';' expected is displayed, even though i have already included the same in the code.

Program:

```
class E

{

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          int i;
          int i++ ;
         // System.out.println(i);
          //System.out.println(j);
     }
}
```

After Running:

```
E.java:6: error: ';' expected                                                                                                                                                             
          int i++ ;
```

Comment: Compiler is not perfect. In this case it doesn't complain about lack of `;` at the end of mentioned line, but at start of it (which means that you missed at line before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javac`'s parser isn't amazingly great at giving errors or suggested fixes. The issues in your code are that:

1. `int i++` is not a valid declaration. If you want to increment `i`, just write `i++;`.
2. The second line is not valid unless `i` is initialized to a value.
3. You may as well assign `i++` to `j`. In that case you would want a *pre-increment* in the form of `++i`.

In total, the following are all valid:

```
int i = 0; // or some other value
i++;
```

or

```
int i = 0; // or some other value
int j = ++i; // also increments `i`
```

or

```
int i = 0; // or some other value
int j = i + 1; // doesn't modify value of i
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be,

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      int i=0;//local variable should be initialized before  use 
      i++ ;//not int i++.you have created it already.
 }
```